# How to implement/mimic jQuery UI's datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want to do is the following:

I have an `<input>` element and `onclick` of that input, I toggle a certain `<div>` (please see below)

```
<div>
   <table>
      <tr>...</tr>
      ...
      ...
   </table>
</div>
```

When I click a row on the table above, I want to trigger an event (ex. put a certain value to `<input>` above and then hide the whole `<div>`. I have made it to work this far.

**Issue:** When the div is shown but **NO** `<tr>` was clicked (ex. the background is clicked), I want to hide the `<div>` this time also. So I put `onblur` event for the `<input>` and hides the div when this happens. This works.

**Problem:** BUT now, when I properly select a `<tr>`, the `onblur` is triggered FIRST, so the div and table gets hidden and no tr onclick is triggered. :(

**My Solution so far:** I removed the onblur event and made something like

```
$(document).mousedown(function() {
   If event.target == myDiv
      dont hide div, so onclick is triggered (manully hide later anyway)
   else //background is clicked
      hide div yey
});
```

**Question:** Is this a decent workaround? Or is there a better way? I want to know how jQuery UI implements this since I saw that datepicker is also a div. Sorry but my level of jQuery still does not allow me to properly read their implementation :/ If someone is kind enough to explain to me. Thank you.

Comment: Why not just use jQuery ui? You can roll your own custom version if you are worried about your page being to heavy [link](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

Comment: @NickTomlin because he probably isn't actually making a datepicker

Comment: You need to have a throttle on the input's blur event that only hides the div if the div isn't interacted with. Essentially, use a setTimeout, and on any event in the table, clear the timeout.

Comment: Nick, I can't sir. I am just making something "similar" but not a datepicker. Basically, I want a "datepicker" functionality except the calendar. lol haha

Comment: @KevinB, thanks for the suggestion sir. What is an ideal duration of this "throttle"? for the next 0.5s? or?

Comment: 0 should be enough(which is actually 4ms), though i'd do 10ms to be safe.

Comment: However, if you do it this way, how then do you hide the table if interacting with it for some reason doesn't?

Comment: I'm sorry sir, I did not understand your previous question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like

```
someTimeout = setTimeout(function(){ someFunction(); }, someDuration) 

$("#someID").click(function() {
   clearTimeout(someTimeout );
});
```

Comment: Yeah this is like something I did also. Thanks anyway.